# How to fix messed-up git master after incorrect rebase?

Tags: git, gerrit

We are using git (and gerrit), but everyone on the project is new to git, which is how we made  the following mistake:

- We were all using the master branch for our commits.
- We created a separate branch testbranch for some side development.
- After a while, we needed to rebase testbranch to master to pick up some changes in master that were needed in testbranch.
- What we should have done (I think) was:

  - git rebase master testbranch
- However what we did was:

  - git rebase testbranch master
  - git push origin HEAD:refs/for/testbranch
- This, we realize now, took all the recent master changes and pushed them on top of all the testbranch changes.
- We unfortunately did the above a total of **4 times** over the course of a few months, with a large number of updates each time.
- We are now done with testbranch and want to merge all the changes from testbranch back into master.
- However this is not working - probably obviously - because testbranch already has all the changes from master in it, and the number of files and conflicts are huge, and get/gerrit (not sure which) keeps giving merge errors.

At this point:

- What can we do to recover?
- Should we cherry-pick all the changes from testbranch?  But how do we identify them when they are mixed with changes rebased from master?
- Should we rename master to old_master and rename testbranch to be the new master?  If so, how do we do this?

Thanks very much for any answers.

Comment: Can you precis (as simply and minimally as possible) what your commit history looks like at this stage?

Comment: The commit history for master is simple - it only contains the items that were committed into it.  The commit history for testbranch is - basically - a set of changes made in testbranch followed by a set of changes from master, repeated 4 times.  Looking at it visually looks like a complete mess.

Answer (score 1):

First a quick PSA. You should not be rebasing branchs in served repositories. In the scenario you outline you should be merging master into testbranch. This will add your master changes onto testbranch. By rebasing you are re-writing the history of a public branch (a branch that is cloned by others) and this will cause no end of problems for developers cloning your repository.

That said, if you had successfully rebased master to testbranch then master should have all the changes of master + testbranch. I think this is what you want. You should be able to verify that master has all the changes you want (i.e. all your testbranch changes) If this is the case then you can just move forward using your current master.

If there are additional changes on testbranch that haven't been rebased to master then you'll want to merge those to master. The merge should be straight forward since master and testbranch are generally the same due to your previous rebases.

The fact that you're getting merge conflicts is odd. I would recommend creating a fresh clone when trying the merge. The rebasing you've done against the public repository is likely to confuse any clone that is pulling/fetching changes.

Alternately if you can verify that testbranch has all the change you want you can try the "rename branch" plan you outline in the question. To do that:

1. Select "Projects" from the gerrit top menu
2. Select "Branches" from the project sub-menu
3. Create a branch called old_master and set the "Initial Revision" to be "master". This will create a new branch called old_master pointing to where master is currently pointing. You should see it in the branch list with the same revision hash as master.
4. Check the box next to "master" and hit the delete button to remove branch master.
5. Create a new branch called master with the Initial Revision being testbranch   You should see master in the branch list with the same revision hash as testbranch

The new master is now the same as testbranch

You will need to tell all developers to create a fresh clone and stop using any old clones.